# Realtime Database Rules with Pushed Objects

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a Realtime Database that pushes objects of the following structure into the DB.

```
Teams
- 0
-- Players
--- 0
---- ID
--- 1
---- ID
- 1
--- 0
---- ID
--- 1
---- ID
```

Basically, there are two teams, each team has up to two players, and each player has an ID. Once a game is saved, the game object is pushed to the DB. I am able to get the game data from /games/[unique-ID-generated-by-pushed]

Currently, all my (authenticated) users are able to read all the data under /games. I would like to restrict this: users are to only see games that they were involved in.

I managed to get this far with my rules.

```
{
  "rules":
  {
    "games":
    {
      "$match_id":
      {
    ".read": "data.child('$match_id').child('teams').child('0').child('players').child('0').child('ID').val() == auth.uid ||
        data.child('$match_id').child('teams').child('0').child('players').child('1').child('ID').val() == auth.uid ||
        data.child('$match_id').child('teams').child('1').child('players').child('0').child('ID').val() == auth.uid ||
        data.child('$match_id').child('teams').child('1').child('players').child('1').child('ID').val() == auth.uid"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

It isn't elegant, but works when I am querying /games/[unique-ID]. I don't seem to be getting any DataChanged event from /games reference, however, which is what I need.

Any idea how I can proceed from here? Or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only allow read access to a game to players that were in that game, something like this should be enough in your current data structure:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "games": {
      "$match_id": {
      ".read": "data.child('teams/0/players/0/ID').val() == auth.uid ||
                data.child('teams/0/players/1/ID').val() == auth.uid ||
                data.child('teams/1/players/0/ID').val() == auth.uid ||
                data.child('teams/1/players/1/ID').val() == auth.uid"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Changes from your rules:

- The `child($match_id)` seems like a mistake, so I removed it.
- You can pass an entire path to `child`, which makes the rules a lot shorter.

If you'd like simpler rules, consider keeping an (additional) simpler list of all players for the game:

```
games
  gameid1
    players
      player1id: true
      player2id: true
      player3id: true
      player4id: true
```

Then the read rule can be a single clause:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "games": {
      "$match_id": {
      ".read": "data.child('players').child(auth.uid).exists()"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially you're trading simpler code/rules for more complex data in this case.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right about the `child($match_id)` thing. Sorry it was a mistake when I was simplifying the rules before posting here. I've tried your first suggestion, it works for querying `/games/[game-ID]`, but not for querying `/games`, permission is still not granted. I suspect the `".read"` property should be within the `"games"` scope but out of `"$match_id"`?

Thanks a million for your suggestion on shortening the `child` parameter though, it tidied up things a lot =)

Comment: I've given it more thought and now I think what I'm asking for is probably impossible. I'm hoping for queries to `/games` to return the nodes with read permission and ignoring those without. A confirmation whether this can be accomplished would be appreciated - I may have to restructure my DB to work around this...

Comment: Firebase Database security rules cannot be used to filter data. For a lot more detail on this, read some of the previous [questions mentioning 'rules are not filters'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).

Comment: OK. Thanks for the confirmation. I get it now.